# Steadiness of CVDisplayLink timer when on battery power

Tags: macos, timer, metal, core-video

I'm trying to get an animation to run smoothly, at the refresh rate of the display without screen tearing. The animation is rendered using Metal. As far as I understand Apple tells you to use CVDisplayLink based timers for this, and that is what I've done.

Everything works fine on desktop computers and on laptops when they are connected to a power adaptor. However, when the laptops run on battery, especially when they battery isn't full, I can see very noticeable stuttering in the animation. There is no tearing, though. It seems like the timer is not fired on every screen refresh.

I'm pretty sure this is not because the CPU is throttled down. The CPU utilisation is below 10% and the animation takes less than 2ms to calculate and render; and at 60Hz it would have 16ms to do so.

For what it's worth, this is how I set up the timer:

```
private func makeDisplayLink(window: NSWindow) -> CVDisplayLink
{
    func displayLinkOutputCallback(_ displayLink: CVDisplayLink, _ inNow: UnsafePointer<CVTimeStamp>, _ inOutputTime: UnsafePointer<CVTimeStamp>, _ flagsIn: CVOptionFlags, _ flagsOut: UnsafeMutablePointer<CVOptionFlags>, _ displayLinkContext: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> CVReturn {
        unsafeBitCast(displayLinkContext, to: MetalScreenSaverView.self).animateOneFrame()
        return kCVReturnSuccess
    }

    var link: CVDisplayLink?
    let screensID = UInt32(window.screen!.deviceDescription["NSScreenNumber"] as! Int)
    CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplay(screensID, &link)
    CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(link!, displayLinkOutputCallback, UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()))
    return link!
}
```

And later I'm starting the link by calling `CVDisplayLinkStart` with the link as the argument. The full code, if you are interested can be found at: https://github.com/thoughtworks/dancing-glyphs/blob/master/Library/MetalScreenSaverView.swift

Any ideas? Can I tell OS X somehow to ensure that the timer is fired on every screen refresh? Is this an issue with Metal? I've seen games and screen savers that run fine on battery, but I assume the use OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your code correctly, you're assuming that `CVDisplayLink` is called at some unchangeable interval. That's not promised at all. The system is absolutely free to modify the refresh interval or drop frames. All real-time systems must include the ability to drop frames. That's the heart of what it means to be "real-time."

You're passed the "currently displayed" time and the "target output" time. You're supposed to use those to compute the correct frame for the target output. I don't see you making use of the output time in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you write, and even though I'm basing the animation on time elapsed, retrieved with `CACurrentMediaTime`, I'll try to see whether using the time passed in as an argument to the call-back will make a difference. That said, my real question is what approach to take when you want to get a timer that doesn't "skip frames" as long as my code is fast enough and the system isn't under heavy load otherwise. Game devlopers must have a way to do this, or their games would miss frames on battery, too, right?

Comment: The system is free to drop frames for power savings. I believe you can take a power assertion to request that the system not go into lower power mode, but this is abusive unless you really must have it (since you'll burn the battery much faster). In general if you're using the output time (not current time), it should be smooth. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/711/

Comment: To be honest, I can't reproduce the stuttering now, even when using `CACurrentMediaTime`. In any case, though, using the output time passed to the call-back, as suggested in your answer, is an improvement, and I've implemented it now. So, I'm going to accept this as the correct answer (for me).